# How to display image assets and their titles in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, image, listview, swiftui

I'm trying to create a List view that displays 4 different images and their respective titles.
The code I have displays the 4 different titles, that is, the raw value of the enum `backgroundOptions`. But it only shows one of the 4 different images under each of the 4 template titles.
According to Apple's documentation the `Image` struct wants a String datatype. So when I explicitly type in the name of one of the images in a String, all 4 spaces in the List show the same template.

It seems like the `ForEach` is not iterating through the 4 images. Can anyone help me see what I am missing?

My Data file looks like this:

```
import Foundation

struct Template {
    var template: Templates
    
    init(template: Templates) {
      self.template = template 
    }
}

struct Templates {
  var backgroundOptions: BackgroundOptions
      
  enum BackgroundOptions: String, CaseIterable {
    case blank = "Blank"
    case fullBorder = "Full Border"
    case laurelWreath = "Laurel Wreath"
    case simpleLine = "Simple Lines"
  }
}
```

My View file looks like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TemplatesView: View {
 
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Text("Choose a Template to Edit").font(.headline)
        List{
            ForEach(Templates.BackgroundOptions.allCases,
                         id: \.self) { backgroundOptions in
                ZStack {
                    Image(backgroundOptions.rawValue) 
                     .resizable()
                     .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                   Text(backgroundOptions.rawValue)
                     .font(.title)
                }
              }
            }
          }
        .navigationTitle("Epic Foundries")
    }
  }
}
 

struct TemplatesView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TemplatesView()
    }
}
```

The images I want to use are saved under the "Assets" folder. They are named:

```
blank 
fullBorder
laurelWreath
simpleLine
```

I'm a noob, so this is all the code I have so far. I realize there might be the need for a ModelView file. The goal is to give users a template to select that they can edit in a different view.

Comment: The names are case sensitive, spaces sensitive too. The raw value should match exactly as in assets.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because the raw values of the enums do not match the image names you are trying to display. So you can probably solve in at least four ways:

1. Update the raw values to reflect the actual image names.
2. Update the image names to reflect the raw values.
3. Use the enum value as the name for the image to load.
4. Add a computed property to the enum to deliver the corresponding image name.

Option 3 is done like this:

replace `Ìmage(backgroundOptions.rawValue)`

with `Image("\(backgroundOptions)")`

Option 4 could be added to the enum like this:

```
var imageName: String {

    // If the enum values correspond to the names then the
    // implementation can be kept simple. Otherwise, a switch
    // could be used to implement
    "\(self)"
}
```

...then you use like this: `Image(backgroundOptions.imageName)`

Comment: Option 3 is what I was looking for. Thank you so so much! Such simple change, but made such a big difference!

Comment: @YKWIBN As you can see, I updated the answer with a fourth option. This is actually the one I would recommend, as it means the knowledge of how an enum value maps to an image name is contained within the enum itself. If it ever needs to be changed, it only needs to be changed in that one place.